# should i take this variable which consist only 1 question in factor analysis? (all other variables are based on multiple questions)

Tags: spss, factor-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis, confirmatory-factor

I'm conducting a study on internet shopping adoption. I'm using a structural model from a research paper. My supervisor has asked me to conduct a factor analysis using SPSS. I'm quite weak in stats and am not familiar with SPSS.

There is one variable "Behavioral Intention" which is based on only one question (not multiple questions): "would you buy service next year?". It is a likert type scale.

The factor analysis should have put this question separately but it is putting it with other question. I cannot get the factor analysis to make a separate factor only for this question no matter what I try.

Should I not use this question in factor analysis since it is being grouped with other questions?

I cannot eliminate this question either since it is the sole representative of my variable "Behavioral Intention". my model will become unstable

I would very much appreciate your help.[image: model to understand]

Comment: Attention to capitalisation and punctuation severely needed here. Look around you: the vast majority of questions don't look like texts to your lover, but make an effort at presentation. I may not be the only person who refuses to read this on principle.

Comment: How many number of items included in that question / construct ?. I suggest you to read the Multivariate Data Analysis book by Hair,Black,Babin & Anderson (2011) ,published by Prentice Hall and refer back to the original measurement from the previous study. I used one construct comprised of three items using 7 point likert scale prior to proceed to Structural Model.

Comment: I tried to read this. But I am not going to try too hard. I join @NickCox

Comment: Hi Talha: I edited your question to have paragraphs, use complete sentences, and have proper capitalization.  It still has some serious readability issues.  I think you have a valid question in there somewhere, but you probably need a complete re-write to make it clear.

Comment: thank you. i appreciate it. english isnt my native language.

Comment: @Sari the variable name is Behavioural Intention based on a single question which i ve mentioned in my query above. its based on 5 point likert scale. Other variables are based on multiple questions. this book is not available here in Pakistan. Karachi :(

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to perform factor analysis on a single variable. Begin by reading the excerpt of the tag wiki for [factor-analysis](/questions/tagged/factor-analysis) (hover your cursor over this tag). The smaller number of factors in your single variable case is zero. You have no covariances to consider except the item's own variance. It simply doesn't make sense to try factor analysis on one variable.

Your next step should probably be consulting with your advisor. It sounds like he or she has tossed you into the deep end without a life preserver. Fortunately, there's plenty of information already here, and on Wikipedia, and in books, that could've told you what I've told you in the above paragraph. What your advisor actually wants to know is what none of us can tell you. Chances seem good that your advisor had nothing unusual in mind. Hence I again suggest you read Wikipedia, search for an introduction to factor analysis, or read a statistics textbook chapter on it. Any of these will answer the simple question of how to perform a factor analysis. How to do this in SPSS specifically would probably be judged an off-topic question.

---

**Edit:** Thanks for adding the path diagram. It looks like you have five constructs in a structural equation model. With only one variable for `Behavioral Intention`, you probably won't want to include it in a factor analysis unless the objective is to demonstrate that it doesn't load as strongly on a factor as the factor's intended indicators. Factor loadings are correlations between a latent variable and manifest (measured) variables. Ideally, each item that measures a factor will have a loading above $\lambda\ge.7$, meaning the factor explains at least 50% of the item's variance. For instance, you'd want the items that measure `Innovativeness` to have factor loadings $\ge.5$ (being a little more lenient and realistic) on a single factor, and items that measure other latent constructs (including `Behavioral Intention`) to load primarily on other factors, or in the case of `Behavioral Intention`, weakly on all factors (say $\lambda\le.3$ or so).

If you were to factor analyze all your items, you'd hope for a four-factor solution (i.e., large eigenvalues for the first four factors that descend gradually in magnitude, and much lower, roughly equal eigenvalues for all others after the fourth). Parallel analysis or [VSS](https://personality-project.org/r/vss.html) might be the easiest analyses to interpret if you're inexperienced with reading scree plots or choosing the number of factors by other means. Your path diagram indicates expected relationships among these factors, so use an oblique rotation, not an orthogonal one, after extracting factors (again, hopefully four will be the right number). This will give you factor pattern loadings that are worth interpreting as described above: all items intended to measure the same factor should load strongly together on the same factor, and have weak loadings on other factors. Your one item for `Behavioral Intention` should load weakly on all factors.

If you were to just factor analyze the items for one factor at a time, you'd want to see a single-factor solution for each, and all loadings on the general (first) factor greater than $\lambda\ge.5$ or so. You don't need to rotate a single-factor solution. If you were to add the item for `Behavioral Intention` to the factor analysis of any single factor, you'd just want to see it have a much lower loading, lower communality, or higher uniqueness, as compared to all the other items. This should be an easy-enough way to test its discriminant validity; e.g., factor analyze all the items measuring `Innovativeness` together with the `Behavioral Intention` item. However, one problem with this method is that it would increase your Type I / false alarm / $\alpha$ error rate to perform the comparison multiple times. Might be worth doing anyway though just to be overly liberal in your discriminant validity problem detection approach.

Since it looks like you have preexisting theoretical measurement models available, you could also (probably should, really) use confirmatory methods like structural equation modeling (SEM). Modification indices could tell you if an item from one factor correlates too strongly with a factor it's not supposed to measure directly. However, I think Amos is the SPSS brand SEM software, so you might need access to that to perform this analysis without learning a new software environment. (Like R! I could even give you code in that, but not in Amos...)

Comment: thank you. im meeting my supervisor this Friday. i ll discuss this issue with him. there re pages which shows how to perform it but neither has discussed issues related with it like this.
im sure he is gonna let me drop the variable from analysis. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If the factor analysis is putting that question with other questions then is *is* related.

Unless you are misinterpreting the results of the factor analysis.

FA constructs linear combinations of variables and calls them factors. Every factor includes every question, just with different weights. If the question that you are worried about has a high weight (positive or negative) in a factor where other questions also have high weights, then it is related to those questions.

So, you've learned something about the questions or about your sample.

Comment: sir i know it is not related. the problem is that it is the only sole question for my variable i.e "behavioral intention". i can't eliminate it. and FA analysis doesnt make a factor simply for this question. if you or anyone provides me email address, i ll mail you my results.

Comment: The factor analysis proves that it is related. Factor analysis does sometimes put one question by itself; in fact, the later factors are often one question by itself. You have shown that either "behavioral intention" is related to something else or that the question you think measures "behavioral intention" is also measuring something else. See my profile for more info about me, if you like, including my website